# Proof that $(p_n) \to p$ if and only if every open $U \ni p$ contains all but finitely many $p_n$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(p_n)$ a sequence in $X$. Prove that $(p_n) \to p$ if and only if every open set containing $p$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Here is my attempt.

Suppose $p_n \to p$, and let $U \ni p$ be an open set. As $U$ is open, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon} (p) \subset U$. By convergence of $(p_n)$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$, corresponding to this $\epsilon$, such that for all $n \geq N$, we have $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$, i.e., $p_n \in B_{\epsilon} (p) \subset U$. So $U$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, namely $n < N$, for which $p_n$ need not live in $U$.

Conversely, suppose that every open set $U \ni p$ contains all but finitely many points of $p_n$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $B_{\epsilon} (p)$. Then $B_{\epsilon} (p)$ is an open set containing $p$, so it contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. Let $n_0$ be the largest $n$ for which $p_n \not \in B_{\epsilon} (p)$, and set $N := n_0 + 1$. Then for all $n > N$, we have $p_n \in B_{\epsilon} (p)$, i.e., $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$, so $p_n \to p$, as desired.

How does this look? Is this fully rigorous, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct and rigorous enough.